# How to prompt again if user input is not valid?

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, calculator

I know how to check if user input is not valid but I don't know how to ask again.

In my code if user input is string then it says "Invalid input" and exits the console

But I want it to ask again "Please enter your first number: " until answer is number!

I tried while loop but I failed.

Can anyone show me how to do it please ?

```
    int Summation = 0;

    Console.Write("\n\t\t\tPlease enter your first number: ");
    string firstNumberInput = Console.ReadLine();

    if (!int.TryParse(firstNumberInput, out int FirstNumber))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t\tInvalid input!");
        Console.Beep();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    Console.Write("\n\t\t\tPlase enter your second number: ");
    string secondNumberInput = Console.ReadLine();

    if (!int.TryParse(secondNumberInput, out int SecondNumber))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t\tInvalid input!");
        Console.Beep();
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    Console.Write("\n\t\t\tNow chose your operator(+, -, *, /): ");
    string Operator = Console.ReadLine();

    switch (Operator)
    {
        case "+":
            Summation = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;
            break;

        case "-":
            Summation = FirstNumber - SecondNumber;
            break;

        case "*":
            Summation = FirstNumber * SecondNumber;
            break;

        case "/":
            Summation = FirstNumber / SecondNumber;
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t\tThe operator is not valid!");
            Console.Beep();
            Environment.Exit(0);
            break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t\tYour answer is {0}", Summation);
```

Comment: *"I tried while loop but I failed."* - A loop is exactly how you'd do that.  But I don't see one in your code.  What did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: I know it can be done with while loop but I don't know how to do it exactly.
That's what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you want to repeat an action, what you're talking about is a "loop".  For a loop you just need a body of code to repeat and a condition on which to remain in the loop.  For example, consider something like this:

```
// declare your variables
var firstNumber = 0;
var validInput = false;

// loop until you have valid input
while (!validInput)
{
    // get the input
    Console.Write("\n\t\t\tPlease enter your first number: ");
    var firstNumberInput = Console.ReadLine();

    // validate it
    validInput = int.TryParse(firstNumberInput, out firstNumber);

    // if it was invalid, notify the user
    if (!validInput)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t\tInvalid input!");
        Console.Beep();
    }
}
```

This would continuously loop until the input is valid.